# Scala XML Node get xpath

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

Is there any way, how to get full xpath to XML Node in Scala? I have:

```
val count = ((sport \\ "android.widget.TextView") filter {t => (t \ "@resource-id").text == "my.app.test:id/sport_count"}) \ "@text"
```

And I need something like **count.getFullXPath** which returns String with XPath.